# Cannot assign data form DataBase to MutableLiveData

Tags: android, kotlin, variables, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

cannot show selected data by using LiveData.

my viewModel:

```
  //LiveData which get data from DB
  private var _selectedDate = MutableLiveData<List<EventsEntity>>()
    val selectedDate: LiveData<List<EventsEntity>>
    get() = _selectedDate

    //function for getting data
    fun selectDate(day:String){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _selectedDate.value = dataSource.getEventsByDay(day)
        }
    }
```

My Dao:

```
@Query("Select * from events where day = :day ")
suspend fun getEventsByDay(day :String):List<EventsEntity>
```

My UI:

```
android:text="@{viewModel.selectedDate.toString()}"
```

When I calling coroutine function from fragment class - my UI is not changed. Where I made an error?

Calling coroutine from fragment class:

```
  binding.calender.setOnDateChangeListener(CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener { calendarView, year, month, dayOfMonth ->

            var date: String = dayOfMonth.toString() + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year

            Toast.makeText(context,date, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            //viewModel.showEvents(date)
            viewModel.selectDate(date)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel.selectedDate has the type `LiveData`, so this:

`android:text="@{viewModel.selectedDate.toString()}"`

will not work. You will need to call it this way:

`android:text="@{viewModel.selectedDate.value.toString()}"`

to convert the list to a string and set it as text.